# Testing groups in a Pandas groupby for equality within each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to

```
df = {'Col1':['a','a','b','b','c','d','d'],'Col2':[1,2,1,1,3,2,3]}
```

My goal is to identify duplicates in Col1 and then check if their values for Col2 are **NOT** the same. Once I can identify the values that match this condition, my goal is to create a dataframe for these results and assign a unique duplicate ID to link them. After performing this check, the resulting dataframe from the sample above would look like

```
result = {'Col1':['a','a','d','d'],'DuplicateID':[1,1,2,2]}
```

I can easily obtain the table with the duplicates and a linking duplicateID in this manner:

```
duplicates = df.loc[data['Col1'].map(df['Col1'].value_counts()) > 1]
duplicates['DupelicateID'] = duplicates.groupby('Col1', sort=False).grouper.group_info[0] + 1
```

However, I am stuck on where in the code and how to query and return only the duplicate groups that are not equivalent in their 'Col2' value.

Comment: That's a dictionary, not a dataframe

Comment: What would be the proper way to represent a pandas dataframe in stackoverflow? A method I commonly use to build a sample dataframe when testing is the pd.from_dict() method

Comment: we should be able to copy/paste your code and run it.  Look at my answer for an example of how you could do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set` to get the distinct `Col2` values per group.  If that's greater than 1 you have different values.  `filter` will help you return those values, and you can use `ngroup` to add a distinct id to each group.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['a','a','b','b','c','d','d'],'Col2':[1,2,1,1,3,2,3]})

dupes = df.groupby('Col1').filter(lambda x: len(set(x['Col2']))>1)

dupes['DuplicateID'] = dupes.groupby('Col1').ngroup()+1
```

Output

```
    Col1    Col2    DuplicateID
0   a          1    1
1   a          2    1
5   d          2    2
6   d          3    2
```